# JavaScript Function Exercise Day Of The Week

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, if-statement, null

I need to make a function that takes an integer from `1` to `7`.

If the number is less than `1` or greater than `7`, the function should return `null`. Then each number should represent the day of the week.

So if I try something like function return `Day(1)`, it should give me an output of `'Sunday'`,

```js
> Day(2)
⋖ 'Monday'
```

```js
> Day(3)
⋖ 'Tuesday'
```

And so on...

So this is my approach, yet it didn't work and I think my syntax is a little bit sketchy, so I would like to get the correct approach :)

```js
const weekDAY = new Array(7);
weekDAY[1] = 'Sunday' ;
weekDAY[2] = 'Monday';
weekDAY[3] = 'Tuesday';
weekDAY[4] = 'Wednesday';
weekDAY[5] = 'Thursday';
weekDAY[6] = 'Friday';
weekDAY[7] = 'Saturday';

function returnDay(x) {
  return (x < 1) || (x > 7) ? null :
  } else {
    let thisDay = weekDAY[x]
    return thisDay;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect. Use either an `if - else` statement or a `? :` expression, not both.

Comment: Re *"it didn't work"*: Can you be more specific? E.g., what happened? What were the symptoms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use an 'else' with the ternary operator. A ternary operator can be used instead of using an *if-else* block, but you cannot use a ternary operator with an *else* block like you have used in your solution.

Also, Arrays are 0 based. Therefore, you should ideally start allocation from 0. Like I've done in the below code snippet.

**How an if-else block works:**

```
if(condition){
    // If 'condition' is true this code executes
} else {
    // If 'condition' is not true, this code executes
}
```

**How the ternary operator works:**

```
(condition) ? {code when condition is true} : {code when condition is false};
```

**So in your case that would be:**

```
return (x<1) || (x>7) ? null : weekDay[x];
```

**The entire solution in your case would be:**

```js
const weekDAY= new Array(7);
weekDAY[0] = 'Sunday' ;
weekDAY[1] = 'Monday';
weekDAY[2] = 'Tuesday';
weekDAY[3] = 'Wednesday';
weekDAY[4] = 'Thursday';
weekDAY[5] = 'Friday';
weekDAY[6] = 'Saturday';

function returnDay(x){
  return (x < 1) || (x > 7) ? null : weekDAY[x];
}

//Calling the function for result and printing it to the console
//using console.log()
console.log(returnDay(2));
```

Answer (score 3):

As [Pointy says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64715531/javascript-function-exercise-day-of-the-week/64715712#comment114424787_64715531), your function should look like this:

```
function returnDay(x){
    return x < 1 || x > 7 ? null : weekDAY[x]
}
```

Or like this:

```
function returnDay(x){
  if(x < 1 || x > 7) {
    return null;
  }
  else {
    return weekDAY[x];
  }
}
```

Comment: ...the first expression can be shortened to `return weekDAY[x] || null;`

Answer (score 1):

The closing brace is closing the function which you used with the ? operator.

```
const weekDAY = new Array(7);
weekDAY[1] = 'Sunday' ;
weekDAY[2] = 'Monday';
weekDAY[3] = 'Tuesday';
weekDAY[4] = 'Wednesday';
weekDAY[5] = 'Thursday';
weekDAY[6] = 'Friday';
weekDAY[7] = 'Saturday';

function returnDay(x) {
    if(x < 1 || x > 7) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return weekDAY[x];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Array's are zero-based, meaning the first index starts from 0 so your code should look like this

```
weekDAY[0] = 'Sunday' ; 
weekDAY[1] = 'Monday';
weekDAY[2]= 'Tuesday';
weekDAY[3] = 'Wednesday';
weekDAY[4] = 'Thursday';
weekDAY[5] = 'Friday';
weekDAY[6] = 'Saturday';
```

Alternatively you can write this a fewer lines by doing this,

```
weekDay = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']
```

The Function your looking for could look something like this

```
function returnDay(day) {
  if (day > weekDay.length+1 || day < 1) {
    return null
  } else {
    return weekDay[day-1]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using a `switch` statement

```js
const dayOfTheWeek = day => {
   if (day < 1 || day > 7) return null

   switch (day) {
    case 1:
      return 'Sunday'
      break
    case 2:
      return 'Monday'
      break
    case 3:
      return 'Tuesday'
      break
    case 4:
      return 'Wednesday'
      break
    case 5:
      return 'Thursday'
      break
    case 6:
      return 'Friday'
      break
    case 7:
      return 'Saturday'
   }
}

console.log(dayOfTheWeek(7))
```

### Using a `ternary` operator

If you have to use the array you gave to use in your example then you can do something like this:

```js
const weekDAY= new Array(7)
weekDAY[1] = 'Sunday'
weekDAY[2] = 'Monday'
weekDAY[3] = 'Tuesday'
weekDAY[4] = 'Wednesday'
weekDAY[5] = 'Thursday'
weekDAY[6] = 'Friday'
weekDAY[7] = 'Saturday'

const dayOfTheWeek = day => {
  return day < 0 || day > 7 ? null : weekDAY[day]
}


console.log(dayOfTheWeek(3))
```

### Conditional (ternary) operator

In your example, you seem to have misunderstood the "conditional (ternary) operator". For example, let’s convert the one we used in my solution to a regular `if/else` statement.

Ternary operator:

```js
return day < 0 || day > 7 ? null : weekDAY[day]
```

Regular `if/else` statement:

```js
if (day < 0 || day > 7) {
  return null
} else {
  return weekDAY[day]
}
```

Syntax:

```js
condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse
```

---

### Arrays are indexed at `0`

Your array starts at `1`. This actually doesn't mean your array is indexed at `1`. It will still be indexed at `0`. If we log the `weekDAY` array, we will see this:

```
[
  undefined,
  "Sunday",
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday"
]
```

As you can see, we have the `0` index set to `undefined`. This right now isn't an issue for us (because we do not allow integers below `1`) in our `dayOfTheWeek` function, but if we decided to loop over this array, we will it loop over `undefined`. This could create an error in our code later on.

To avoid this problem, you should try and declare arrays this way:

```js
weekDAY = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 // create object to store days of the week
const days = {
  1: "Monday",
  2: "Tuesday",
  3: "Wednesday",
  4: "Thursday",
  5: "Friday",
  6: "Saturday",
  7: "Sunday",
};

// create function
function returnDay(num) {
  return num < 1 || num > 7 ? null : days[num];
}

// call function
console.log(returnDay(3)); // Wednesday
console.log(returnDay(8)); // null
console.log(returnDay(0)); // null
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using a conditional:**

```
const weekDAY = new Array();
weekDAY[1] = 'Monday' ;
weekDAY[2] = 'Tuesday';
weekDAY[3] = 'Wednesday';
weekDAY[4] = 'Thursday';
weekDAY[5] = 'Friday';
weekDAY[6] = 'Saturday';
weekDAY[7] = 'Sunday';

function returnDay(x){
    if(x < 1 || x > 7) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return weekDAY[x];
    }
}

console.log(returnDay(1));
console.log(returnDay(7));
console.log(returnDay(4));
console.log(returnDay(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning on [Udemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udemy) and have completed the exercise like this:

```js
function returnDay (num) {
    let daysOfWeek = ['not a day','Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
    return num < 1 || num > 7 ? null : daysOfWeek[num]; 
}
```

Comment: This is the same idea as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64715738/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*

Answer (score 0):

```
const days = {
    1:"Monday",
    2:"Tuesday",
    3:"Wednesday",
    4:"Thursday",
    5:"Friday",
    6:"Saturday",
    7:"Sunday"
 }

const dayNum = Object.values(days);

function returnDay(a) {
    if(a < 1 || a > 7) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return dayNum[a - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why declare an Object if you only use the values and access them by index. This is totally unnecessary waste of time and memory. It will certainly be irrelevant in terms of execution time but that does not make it less of a waste.